# Trouble with using RODBC to access Northwind.accdb file

Tags: r, ms-access

I'm trying to demo SQL queries from within R using the Northwind.accdb file. I visited http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/desktop-northwind-2007-sample-database-TC001228997.aspx and was able to download the .accdt file. I've tried creating a database connection using RODBC with the following two lines, but both return the same error that R is unable to find the file, even though I am certain of its location (on the desktop).

Here are the lines of code that I'm using:

```
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007("Nwind.accdt", uid = "", pwd = "")
conn <- odbcConnectAccess2007("Nwind.accdb", uid = "", pwd = "")
```

The error output I'm getting looks like this:

```
Warning messages:
1: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) :
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLDriverConnect
2: In odbcDriverConnect(con, ...) : ODBC connection failed
```

Very grateful for any pointers you all might have.

Comment: Do you have the correct database driver installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems when using 32 bit drivers on 64 bit Windows. If you have ODBC 32 bit installed, coming with older versions of Office, make sure that you are running 32-bit R (easy with RStudio under Tools).

Or, with 64 bit drivers, use 64 bit R.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Turns out the .accdt file format doesn't lend itself to simple .accdb conversion, so the RODBC function was cracking up. Got the original .accdb file and am good to go.